# asp.net nuget library для определения OS и браузера

Tags: c#, asp.net

Тривиальная задача: нужно по HttpContext.Request иметь имя операционной системы вида iOs 9.1, Windows 10.0 и браузер вида Firefox 40, Chrome 20 и т.д
Скорее всего должна быть какая-то годная готовая либа с обновлением и всем таким. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите [`HttpContext.Request.Browser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities(v=vs.110).aspx)

Обновляется вместе с фреймворком (т.е. не очень часто). Но более-менее точен в определении OS и основных трех браузеров.

Comment: Да, там все хорошо, кроме возможностей форматирования и как получить версию ОС? Platform там есть, да, но без версии.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вам подойдет объект navigator, поддерживаемый всеми адекватными браузерами.  Подробнее [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp). Про userAgent [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp) 
Его, конечно, стоит несколько доработать напильником, но в целом - вполне приемлемое решение, позволяет даже идентифицировать экзотику вроде Vivaldi

З.Ы. Кстати у System.Web.HttpRequest есть строковое свойство UserAgent

Comment: Да хотелось бы это все на бекенде получать с HttpContext.Request